# Por quê .all em uma lista vazia retorna true?

Tags: c#, linq, enumerable

Estava com um erro em uma regra de negócio, e ao investigar, cheguei no seguinte trecho de código, cuja intenção é verificar se todos os processos de uma lista estão ativos:

`return processos.All(proc => proc.Ativo)`

Ao fazer um debug, descobri que `processos` tinha zero elementos. É fácil corrigir, bastaria mudar a condicional para:

`return processos.Any() && processos.All(proc => proc.Ativo)`

Porém, a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx)  oficial afirma que o `.All`:

> Determina se todos os elementos de uma sequência atendem a uma condição.

Se uma lista está vazia, como podem todos os elementos atenderem a uma condição? Ou estou com algum erro de conceito?

Fiz um exemplo reproduzível no [Rextester](http://rextester.com/LIWMHL91313).

Comment: Curiosamente dá para inverter o português de forma a responder à pergunta. Se a lista está vazia não tem nenhum elemento, logo o `.All` testa se nenhum atende a condição. E de facto nenhum atende. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Explicação

De acordo com a documentação caso a sequência seja vazia, será retornado valor `true`.

> **Valor Retornado**
>
> **Type:** *System.Boolean*
>
> `true` se todos os elementos da sequência de origem passarem no teste no predicado especificado **ou se a sequência for vazia**; caso contrário, `false`.

<sub>Fonte: [Microsoft Docs - Método Enumerable.All (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx)</sub>

Comment: É verdade. Deixei escapar esta parte

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a documentação do [método Enumerable.All (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb548541.aspx)

> Valor Retornado
>
> Type: **System.Boolean**
>
> `true` se todos os elementos da
>   sequência de origem passarem no teste no predicado especificado ou se
>   a sequência for vazia; caso contrário, false.

Se analizarmos o [código fonte](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs) deste método do .net Core, podemos ver:

```
public static bool All<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(source));
            }

            if (predicate == null)
            {
                throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(predicate));
            }

            foreach (TSource element in source)
            {
                if (!predicate(element))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Decorticando:

1. serão geradas excessões se `Source` ou `Predicate` são nulas;
2. Para cada elemento de `Source` verifique se o `Predicate` é falso. Se sim retorne false
3. caso todos os elemento não passem no teste dentro do laço, um `return true` é executado

Para o caso de uma lista vazia (que é diferente de uma lista nula), o laço não executado e o`return true` é executado.